# are eclipse juno and tomcat compatible

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I was able to write and test my servlets just fine using Eclipse Indigo and Tomcat, then I loaded Eclipse Juno with ADT (Android Development Tools) and suddenly it won't run Tomcat.  I cannot even see anyplace where I can tell Eclipse that I need to use a server.

I have tried re-downloading Tomcat but that doesn't work as it doesn't send me an executable that I can run and install. Tomcat 7.0.39

Answer (score 0):

Did you download the same Juno package as you did with Indigo?  I'm guessing you accidentally got the download for "Java" rather than the one for "Java EE".  Got to Help->Install New Software, and from the Juno site, choose the "Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools".

Comment: I selected the option: Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development but it said I already had it installed.